# Error on button click for going to next Activity selected from Spinner

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have to open a new activity when an item is selected from the spinner and go button is clicked. But the app stops working when go button is clicked.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String check = branchText.getText().toString();
    String check1 = semText.getText().toString();
    if(check.equals("Information Technology")&&check1.equals("1st"))
    {
        Intent it=new Intent(MainActivity.this, IT1stSem.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
}


public class IT1stSem extends ListActivity {

String[] data = {"Mathematics-I", "Physics-I", "Chemistry", "Engg. Mechanics", "Electrical Science"};
ListView l;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.it1stsem);
    l=getListView();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.it1stsem, data);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView temp = (TextView) v;
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+temp.getText()+ " "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

Comment: Post a complete stack trace of the error from logcat

Comment: Check Out this Image
http://postimg.org/image/mx95j6kf7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Logcat it is clear that you haven't declared your Activity (to which you want to go) in the **Manifest**.

In Manifest, declare your IT1stSem class like this:

```
<activity android:name="yourpackageName.IT1stSem" >
    </activity>
```